# Process image using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a number of microscopic images and I want to apply detection algorithms on those images using OpenCV. For that, I need to apply some image processing methods. But I am not sure which will be the best method for this one.

I applied exposure and contrast from Shotwell (ubuntu software) which works perfectly fine with my case. How I can do the same in OpenCV or any image processing library in python?

I have attached a link to the input and the required image.

Input image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XoY8u5yk0X4620alR61GhoJrd9pJBYji/view?usp=sharing

Required image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13DpbDYdNsOAh1k_ZLHpYV99ddlIF47vB/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but explain what  should be on  the second picture - all different colored isolated points?

Comment: @Leox Thank you for your reply. I am not sure If I understood you correctly. I want to convert into binary images with the proper image processing method so that I will not lose any of those points. Is this clear your doubt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example

```
img=cv2.imread('points.jpg')
hsv_image = cv2.cvtColor(img ,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(hsv_image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_,mask = cv2.threshold(gray, 75, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

I get

[image]

But I'm not sure if I lost some points or added new ones.

Comment: thank you for the help, This is what I need. But with the above code, I am getting and a blank image. Am I missing something?

link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GltcRY-jUVPq0ueQpC28sm-a_ylcpTWw/view?usp=sharing

Comment: very strange, I also get now blank image. Try set up the  lower threshold limit 75 instead of 150, it works  so far

Comment: It was really time-consuming to hard code the value for each image, so I went with detecting those blobs using the object detector model (YOLOv5) it gave me satisfactory results.